What testing strategies/checkpoints for your Generative AI applications
How are you testing your Generative AI ?
Considering its capabilities, the new trend of agentic AI is on the rise. This highlights the importance of having a well-defined testing approach or a good checklist.
I wanted to ask:

What are the patterns or testing strategies you are following beyond basic testing strategies?
What's your approach to identifying and fixing issues? Do you follow any specific checkmarks?

Interesting Response from ChatGPT



Issue
Definition
Strategies




AI Hallucination
Generating factually incorrect or nonsensical outputs,The response provided has data that is not reliable however its sounds plausible or true.
Fact-checking, Human-in-the-loop, Prompt engineering, Training data quality, Model fine-tuning, Post-processing


Bias and Fairness
Generating outputs that unfairly favor certain groups
Bias audits, Fairness metrics, Diverse training data


Ethical and Safety Concerns
Generating harmful, offensive, or inappropriate content
Content moderation, Ethical guidelines, Regular ethical reviews


Coherence and Relevance
Ensuring logical consistency and pertinence to input context
Coherence metrics, Prompt design, Feedback loops


Explainability and Interpretability
Making the model’s decision-making process understandable to users
Explainability tools, Interpretable models, User explanations


Robustness and Reliability
Handling diverse and unexpected inputs reliably
Robustness testing, Error handling, Regular updates and retraining



Here are some other observations:
Example: Adherence to Instructions
Issue: With tools like Meta AI Agents and similar others in Salesforce, we need to check if the response adheres to the instructions, as sometimes it fails to follow the guidelines and guardrails.
Solution: It might be an issue with the instruction, but we need to go back to basics while testing against each instruction to check if it is followed or not. This might become hectic; any alternatives?
Example: Coherence with Knowledge Article Boundaries
Issue: GPT models used as chatbots with a set of knowledge articles sometimes provide results outside the set of knowledge articles as a reference.
Solution: Implement coherence metrics, prompt design, and feedback mechanisms.
Example: Chain of Thought
Issue: In some cases, the generative AI assumes continuity with earlier conversations within the window period, which might cause unnecessary references.
Solution: There should be instructions to cross-verify and provide a note.
Most of these issues can be addressed with effective prompt engineering. However, I am curious about your methods for addressing these issues and any observations you have identified.
